# How does $H$ act on $G^t$ in the wreath product $G^t \wr H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rubiks-cube, wreath-product

I'm reading [this](https://www.lakeheadu.ca/sites/default/files/uploads/77/docs/Daniels_Project.pdf#page28) expository paper about group theory in the Rubik's cube.

I'm a little confused by the definition of the wreath product in this paper.

Example 3.12 on page 12 states that the elements of the wreath product $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3 \wr S_3$ for the set X={0, 1, 2} are

{$(0,0,0) \rho, (1,0,0) \rho, (0, 1, 0) \rho, (0, 0, 1) \rho, (1, 1, 0) \rho, (0, 1, 1) \rho, (1, 0, 1) \rho, (1, 1, 1) \rho$}

where $\rho$ is an element of $S_3$.

My question is: is $\rho$ just an arbitrary element in $S_3$, or is $\rho$ somehow specially chosen? I don't understand how $S_3$ acts on $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ in the same way as $S_3$ acts on the set X.

More generally, I don't understand how, for a direct product $G^t \wr H$, where $H$ acts on a set of size $t$, how $H$ acts on $G^t$. Specifically, which elements of $H$ are acting on $G^t$?

P.s I'd really appreciate it if answers were geared towards a high school student with little formal abstract algebra background. Thank you. :)

Comment: Use `$\{ x\}$` for $\{ x\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S_3$ acts by permuting the entries of a $3$-tuple in $\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \DeclareMathOperator{\Aut}{Aut} (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$. In symbols: given $\pi \in S_3$,
$$
\pi \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, a_{\pi^{-1}(2)}, a_{\pi^{-1}(3)}) \, .
$$
(The inverse is just there for bookkeeping, to make sure this defines a left-, rather than right-, action.)
So for instance, taking $\pi = (1\ 2)$ and $(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (0,1,0)$, then $\pi^{-1} = \pi$ and
$$
\pi \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_2, a_1, a_3) = (1,0,0) \, .
$$
This action induces a homomorphism $\varphi: S_3 \to \Aut((\Z/2\Z)^3)$, which allows us to define the semidirect product $(\Z/2\Z)^3 \rtimes_\varphi S_3$. As a set $(\Z/2\Z)^3 \rtimes_\varphi S_3$ is just the cartesian product $(\Z/2\Z)^3 \times S_3$, so as a set
$$
(\Z/2\Z)^3 \rtimes_\varphi S_3 = \{((a_1, a_2, a_3), \rho) : a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \Z/2\Z, \rho \in S_3\} \, .
$$
However, the multiplication is "twisted" by the action of $S_3$:
\begin{align*}
((a_1, a_2, a_3), \pi) \ ((b_1, b_2, b_3), \rho) &= ((a_1, a_2, a_3) + \pi \cdot (b_1, b_2, b_3), \pi \rho)\\
&= ((a_1, a_2, a_3) + (b_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(2)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(3)}), \pi \rho)\\
&= ((a_1 + b_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, a_2 + b_{\pi^{-1}(2)}, a_3 + b_{\pi^{-1}(3)}), \pi \rho) \, .
\end{align*}

I only defined the wreath product for $S_t$, but the the same thing works for any subgroup of $S_t$, or more generally for any group $H$ with a homomorphism $H \to S_t$. (This is what it means for a group to act on a set of size $t$.)

Comment: Why is $\pi \cdot (b_1, b_2, b_3) = (b_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(2)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(2)})$? Why isn't it $\pi \cdot (b_1, b_2, b_3) = (b_{\pi^{-1}(1)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(2)}, b_{\pi^{-1}(3)})$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!

Comment: No worries. :) "The inverse is just there for bookkeeping, to make sure this defines a left-, rather than right-, action." - why is it necessary to distinguish between left and right group actions here? In which situations is the group action $\pi$ a left action and when is it a right action for the example you posted?

Comment: From my perspective it seems as though defining the group action to be $\pi \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_{\pi(1)}, a_{\pi(2)}, a_{\pi(3)})$ is fine.

Comment: Only a left action of a group $G$ on a set $X$ induces a homomorphism $\varphi: G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$. A right action induces an anti-homomorphism: $\varphi(gh) = \varphi(h) \varphi(g)$. (That is, unless you have your permutations act on $1, \ldots, n$ on the right as well, but this is opposite the usual action of functions: you'd have to write $(x)\sigma$ instead of $\sigma(x)$.)

Comment: No, you really need the inverse; the notation is just rather subtle. You have to remember that the subscripts in the definition are really just denoting the position in the tuple. For example, if you let $\pi = (1\ 2)$ and $\rho = (1\ 2\ 3)$, without the inverse we get the following. $\rho (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_2, a_3, a_1)$. Call this new tuple $b$, with entries $(b_1, b_2, b_3)$, so $b_1 = a_2$, $b_2 = a_3$, $b_3 = a_1$. Then $\pi (b_1, b_2, b_3) = (b_2, b_1, b_3) = (a_3, a_2, a_1)$. But $\pi \circ \rho = (2\ 3)$, so $(\pi \circ \rho) \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_1, a_3, a_2)$.

Comment: These don't agree: we have $\pi \cdot (\rho \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3)) = \pi \cdot (b_1, b_2, b_3) = (a_3, a_2, a_1)$, but $(\pi \circ \rho) \cdot (a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_1, a_3, a_2)$. With the inverses it works out, though.

Comment: This comes up in a more general context, too. Let $X$ and $S$ be sets. Given an action of a group $G$ on a set $X$, we also get an induced action on $S^X$, the set of all functions $f: X \to S$. However, again we need an inverse for this action to work: the induced action is $(g \cdot f)(x) = f(g^{-1}x)$. In the particular case, we can consider triples in $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^3$ as functions $f: \{1, 2, 3\} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. Then the general function action I described becomes the action of $S_3$ in the semidirect product.